# Inserting a column while executing an existing query

Tags: postgresql

I have this query below that parses names within columns based on specific criteria. I would like to augment this query in order to contain an additional column that being an actual column from the adwords_final table, "Key".

```
insert into mk_kw
with a(v) as (
             select "Campaign"
             from adwords_final
             ), 
pre as (
        select split_part(v, '{', 1) a,split_part(v, '{', 2) b
        from a
        )
select split_part(a, '-', 1) ca,
       split_part(a, '-', 2) cb,
       split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) cc,
       split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3),
       split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) || '|', 2) cd,
       '{' || b ce
from pre;
```

The current input table looks like the following,  "Campaign" being the current column in action

```
Campaign                           |Key |
-----------------------------------+--------+
ES-SRC-IOT|Connectivity|SIM|USA|{e}|ES-SRC-IOT|Connectivity|SIM|USA|{e}2017-5
```

The current output of this looks like the following

```
 ca | cb  |    cc     |             cd             |  ce
----+-----+-----------+----------------------------+------
 ES | SRC | IOT       |  Connectivity | SIM | USA  | {e}
```

I would like to add the "Key" Column as the first Column within this output.

Is it possible to add this or would I have to scrap this query entirely?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
TRUNCATE mk_kw;
INSERT INTO mk_kw
with a(v,g) as (
select "Campaign","Key"
from adwords_final
), pre as (
select split_part(v, '{', 1) a,split_part(v, '{', 2) b,g||'' "Key"
from a 
)
select
"Key",
split_part(a, '-', 1) ca,
split_part(a, '-', 2) cb,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) cc,
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3),
split_part(split_part(a, '-', 3), '|', 1) || '|', 2) cd,
'{' || b ce

from pre;
```